# Groovy XML to CSV with deep XML structure

Tags: xml, csv, groovy

I need a groovy script that is transforming a XML structure into a CSV File without a header line.

XML lookes like this:

```
    <stock>
            <field1>Header</field1>
                <field2>H1</field2>
        <positions>
              <data1>Hello</data1>
              <data2>P1</data2>
        </positions>
        <positions>
              <data1>World</data1>
              <data2>P2</data2>
        </positions>
    </stock>
    <stock>
            <field1>Header</field1>
                <field2>H2</field2>
        <positions>
              <data1>Hello</data1>
              <data2>P3</data2>
        </positions>
        <positions>
              <data1>World</data1>
              <data2>P4</data2>
        </positions>
    </stock>
```

I tried this but it is not doing what i need to have.

```
        //parse input
        def parsedXml = new XmlParser().parseText(ins)
        
        def content = new XmlSlurper().parseText(ins)
        def csv = content.stock.positions.inject(header){ result, row ->
         [result, row.children().collect().join('|')].join("\n")
```

CSV should look like this

```
Header|H1
Hello|P1
World|P2
Header|H2
Hello|P3
World|P4
```

any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: please edit your question and provide expected cvs result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could traverse the xml-tree and collect the nodes with matching names:

```
def ins = '''
<root>
    <stock>
        <field1>Header</field1>
        <field2>H1</field2>
        <positions>
            <data1>Hello</data1>
            <data2>P1</data2>
        </positions>
        <positions>
            <data1>World</data1>
            <data2>P2</data2>
        </positions>
    </stock>
    <stock>
        <field1>Header</field1>
        <field2>H2</field2>
        <positions>
            <data1>Hello</data1>
            <data2>P3</data2>
        </positions>
        <positions>
            <data1>World</data1>
            <data2>P4</data2>
        </positions>
    </stock>
</root>
'''
def content = new XmlSlurper().parseText(ins)

def csv = content.depthFirst()
        .findAll { it.name().matches(/(field|data).*/) }
        .collect{ it.text() }.collate(2)
        .collect { it.join("|") }.join("\n")
```

Or if you need a somewhat generic approach where you can extend the number of field and data tags:

```
def csv = content.depthFirst()
        .findAll { it.name() in ["stock", "positions"] }
        .collect { node -> node.children()
                    .findAll{ it.name() != "positions" }
                    .collect{ it.text() } }
        .collect { it.join("|") }.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not super efficient because it reads everything into memory, but this will work:

```
String ​xmlString = """<stocks><stock>             <field1>Header</field1>                 <field2>H1</field2>         <positions>               <data1>Hello</data1>               <data2>P1</data2>         </positions>         <positions>               <data1>World</data1>               <data2>P2</data2>         </positions>     </stock>     <stock>             <field1>Header</field1>                 <field2>H2</field2>         <positions>               <data1>Hello</data1>               <data2>P3</data2>         </positions>         <positions>               <data1>World</data1>               <data2>P4</data2>         </positions>     </stock>​</stocks>"""​​​
def xml = new ​XmlSlurper​().parseText( xmlString )

List<List<String>> output = []
xml.stock.each { stock ->
   output << [stock.field1.text(),stock.field2.text()]
   stock.positions.each { position ->
      output << [ position.data1.text(), position.data2.text() ]
   }
}
println( output.collect { it.join("|") }.join("\n") )
```